# How does this conditional check work in Python?: if lb < num < ub

Tags: python

I recently saw this syntax usage in Python, and tested it:

```
foo = 100
print(-100 <= foo <= 100)
foo = -100
print(-100 <= foo <= 100)
foo = 0
print(-100 <= foo <= 100)
foo = 101
print(-100 <= foo <= 100)
foo = -101
print(-100 <= foo <= 100)
```

which outputs

```
True
True
True
False
False
```

I've been using the 'old-style' syntax with and like `lb < num and num < up`, this new syntax `lb < num < up` intuitively makes sense, but I'm just not sure how the syntax works here. Is the first part of the whole expression `lb < num` return a boolean `__bool` implicitly and is compared with the latter half of the expression `__bool < ub`?

Comment: No, it basically does the equivalent of `lb < num and num < up`. What you described at the end would be `(lb < num) < up`

Comment: It's a single, indivisible syntax - if the left side was evaluated first and then compared to the right side, the results would be rather different (and rather useless).  I've never heard of a language other than Python that supports this.

Comment: @CeliusStingher that page doesn't answer the question, and what OP describes at the end is not right, I think you may have misread it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser handles chained comparison operators specially. `x < y < z` produces a different abstract syntax tree than either `(x < y) < z` or `x < (y < z)`.

You can see this using the `ast` module (I've formatted the output to make the structure a little easier to see):

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("x < y < z"))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(
                           left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
                           ops=[Lt(), Lt()],
                           comparators=[
                               Name(id='y', ctx=Load()),
                               Name(id='z', ctx=Load())
                           ]))])"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("(x<y)<z"))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(
                           left=Compare(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),      
                                        ops=[Lt()],
                                        comparators=[
                                            Name(id='y', ctx=Load())
                                        ]),
                           ops=[Lt()],
                           comparators=[Name(id='z', ctx=Load())]
                          ))])"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("x<(y<z)"))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Compare(
                             left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
                             ops=[Lt()],
                             comparators=[
                                 Compare(left=Name(id='y', ctx=Load()),
                                         ops=[Lt()],
                                         comparators=[Name(id='z', ctx=Load())]
                                 )]))])"
```

A chained comparison produces a single `Compare` node with multiple operators and comparators, while parentheses produce a `Compare` node that has another `Compare` node as its `left` attribute or one of the members of
its `comparator` attribute.

---

From the grammar:

```
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
# <> isn't actually a valid comparison operator in Python. It's here for the
# sake of a __future__ import described in PEP 401 (which really works :-)
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
```

Note that a comparison is *not* a special kind of more general expression, as you might assume. Rather, an expression is *part* of the higher-level comparison construct .

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are
>   comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to
>   a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.
>
> Note that a op1 b op2 c doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between a
>   and c, so that, e.g., x < y > z is perfectly legal (though perhaps not
>   pretty).